# avoiding scraping data from pages already scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

Good evening all,

I am still working on my spider to scrape data from news sites but have run into another problem, my original question is posted here: [Scrapy outputs [ into my .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348425/scrapy-outputs-into-my-json-file) but has been solved.

I have managed to get a little further, having had to make allowances for empty items and adding search functionality I am now trying to scrape only articles that I have not yet scraped, (baring in mind that I may still want to extract links from them). I can't figure out where to put the code that will:

a.) define when last a crawl was done
b.) compare the date of the article with the date of the last crawl.

I may just be struggling with the logic and so I turn to you.

my spider:

```
# tabbing in python is apparently VERY important so be aware and make sure 
# things that should line up do so

# import the CrawlSpider Class, along with it's Rules, (this lets us recursively
# crawl pages)

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

#import the link extractor, this extracts links from pages

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

# import our items as defined in items.py

from basic.items import BasicItem

# import datetime so that we can get the current date and time

import time

# import re which allows us to compare strings

import re

# create a new Spider with the CrawlSpider Class

class BasicSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):

    # Name of the spider, this is used to run it, (i.e Scrapy Crawl basic_spider)

    name = "basic_spider"

    # domains that the spider is allowed to crawl over

    allowed_domains = ["news24.com"]

    # where to start crawling from

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.news24.com',
    ]

    # Rules for the link extractor, (i.e where it's allowed to look for links, 
    # what to do once it's found them, and whether it's allowed to follow them

    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    # defining the callback function

    def parse_items(self, response):

        # defines the Top level XPath where all of our information can be found, needs to be
        # as specific as possible to avoid duplicates

        for title in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):

            # List of keywords to search through.

            key = re.compile("joburg|durban", re.IGNORECASE)

            # extracting the data to compare with the keywords, this is for the 
            # headlines, the join converts it from a list type to a string type

            headlist = title.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()
            head = ''.join(headlist)

            # and this is for the article.

            artlist = title.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]//text()').extract()
            art = ''.join(artlist)

            # if any keywords are found in the headline:

            if key.search(head):
                if last_crawled > response.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                    # define the top level xpath again as python won't look outside 
                    # it's current fuction

                    for thing in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):

                        # fills the items defined in items.py with relevant data

                        item = BasicItem()
                        item['Headline'] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()
                        item["Article"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]/p[1]/text()').extract()
                        item["Date"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                        item["Link"] = response.url

                        # I found that even with being careful about my XPaths I
                        # still got empty fields and lines, the below fixes that

                        if item['Headline']:
                            if item["Article"]:
                                if item["Date"]:
                                    last_crawled = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
                                    yield item

            # if the headline item doesn't match, check the article item.

            elif key.search(art):
                if last_crawled > response.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                    for thing in response.xpath('//*[@id="aspnetForm"]'):
                        item = BasicItem()
                        item['Headline'] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article_special"]//h1/text()').extract()
                        item["Article"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="article-body"]/p[1]/text()').extract()
                        item["Date"] = thing.xpath('//*[@id="spnDate"]/text()').extract()
                        item["Link"] = response.url

                        if item['Headline']:
                            if item["Article"]:
                                if item["Date"]:
                                    last_crawled = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
                                    yield item
```

It's not working but as I mentioned I'm skeptical of the logic anyway, can someone let me know if I'm on the right track here?

thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using `last_crawled` completely out of context. But don't bother much with it, you will be much better of using the [deltafetch](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapylib/blob/master/scrapylib/deltafetch.py) middleware, created for exactly what you are trying to do:

> This is a spider middleware to ignore requests to pages containing
>   items seen in previous crawls of the same spider, thus producing a
>   "delta crawl" containing only new items.

To use `deltafetch`, install `scrapylib` first:

```
pip install scrapylib
```

and after that, enable it in `settings.py`:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapylib.deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
}

DELTAFETCH_ENABLED = True
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, I have come across references to deltafetch in trying to find the answer to this but it didn't SEEM to suite my needs, I sill want to visit the page and extract links from it to follow, (in case there is a new related article or some such). will deltafetch still extract links to follow from a page, even if it doesn't want to extract item data from it?

will have a play around regardless and let you know, thanks for the reply!